# certutil over ssh (RPC server is unavailable)

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2019, rpc, certutil

When executing a `certutil` request from a local powershell everything is ok.

```
PS C:\Users\admuser> certutil -ping -config 'caserver\ca'
Connecting to caserver\ca ...
Server "ca" ICertRequest2 interface is alive (32ms)
CertUtil: -ping command completed successfully.
PS C:\Users\admuser>
```

Doing the same from a Linux host connected with OpenSSH to the same Windows server we get an error.

```
PS C:\Users\admuser> certutil -ping -config 'caserver\ca'
Connecting to caserver\ca ...
Server could not be reached: The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722 RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE) -- (16ms)

CertUtil: -ping command FAILED: 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722 RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)
CertUtil: The RPC server is unavailable.
PS C:\Users\admuser>
```

Any ideas what is wrong with connecting over ssh and then executing the command, both is executed from a local powershell?

Comment: RPC server unavailable means one of the following ports is not open: 135, 49152 through 65535. Windows 101 requires these ports to be open.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is authenticating with a ssh key. If you do this, you are not able to use further authentication, which is required by the `certutil` and hence the RPC service. This behavior is somewhat hidden documented by MS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement

> A remote session opened via key based authentication does not have associated user credentials and hence is not capable of outbound authentication as the user, this is by design.

So if you need further authentication against the MS ecosystem you are not able to use key based authentication. You have to go with username and password for ssh.

Comment: Check and compare environment variables, that may give a clue.

Comment: They are not different.